# Задание шрифта текста кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть код

```css
.show__more {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    
    margin: 30px auto;
    
    background-color: #5f3ec0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="globalcontainer">
        <button class="show__more">Показать еще</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Каким образом задать шрифт текста кнопки?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <i><button class="show__more">Показать еще</button></i>
```

или

```
    <b><button class="show__more">Показать еще</button></b>
```

и т.д.

Comment: а так чтобы задать шрифт текста кнопки непосредственно у текста нельзя?

Comment: Можно - **<button class="show__more"><b>Показать еще</b></button>**